# Migrating Server from 2tb drive to 3tb and MBR to GPT

Tags: 14.04, server, grub2, plex

I've spent 4 days on this and am ready to give up.

I have a Plex Server on Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a 2 TB drive that's almost full.

Goals:

Clone all data to 3TB drive where I will then be using rsync to backup data to another 3tb drive.

Problems:
I discovered I have to use GPT on the 3tb drive. But then I lose the ability to boot.

What I've tried:
I tried using Live USB to create a boot partition using "boot-repair" with various techniques.

My machine would freeze whenever I would boot into a live disk at varying times ranging from 30 seconds to 5 minutes. So I did the boot repair on another machine.

After creating the boot partition, I cloned the main partition with the data from the 2tb to the remainder space on the 3tb, thus giving me the extra ~1TB of room.

Booting worked a couple times on the machine that I did the transfer on, but moving it back to the original machine, it won't see the OS.

If there is a better way, I'm all ears! I just want to up my space to 3tb and have a clone 3tb disk without having to reinstall all my programs and settings from scratch.

My experience level is about 2 years of messing with this server, so I'm no admin, but have a decent technical base.

Thank you!!

Comment: You would really need to do the boot repair on the original machine. If you're using an Ubuntu Live CD and the system is choking or freezing on it like you describe, try using a USB stick, or switching to a lighter-weight distribution like Lubuntu.  How much RAM does the machine in question have?

Comment: I'm using a live USB. Maybe I'll just have to find a CD-R and create a Live CD. I have 4gb of ddr4.

Comment: Often best to just reinstall to new drive and then use cp or rsync to copy data. You also have issues of change from MBR to gpt which changes a lot of internal settings. While you can edit & reinstall grub, it can be a lot of detail to fix. If you want to try to repair post link from Summary Report. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info Use ppa to install into your Ubuntu live installer.

Comment: It's unlikely that a live disc will be any faster than a live USB - it will probably be much slower. I know it's not really your first choice, but honestly oldfred's advice is sound. Copying over your library information and settings to a new installation of Plex is quite easy and will take much less time than copying the files - but your hesitation to reinstall "all your programs and settings from scratch" makes me think you have many other things on there besides Plex.

Comment: Thanks everyone.

I do have other stuff on there. While it's primarily my plex server, I've also used it to try other programs. I have tmux, vsftpd, ssh, plus some other stuff. Is there a way to just rsync the right folders to have all of those files transfer over? 

I'm just thinking of installing a fresh Ubuntu Server on the 3tb with GPT, then if I can rsync the files and media over to make it as near of a clone as possible, then that will work.

Comment: Are you not backing all that up now, so you could reinstall if something major goes wrong? User settings are in /home, you can export list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall. Then if used as server you need all the locations where server type software stores data which may be in /, not /home. See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2368992 And advantage of keeping old drive is that you can reboot into it or mount it to get something you missed first time ( and then add to list of what you should be backing up).